# pip.installed keeps re-installing the same package from github

Tags: salt-stack

I have a state defined to install a package with pip directly from a github repository:

```
cloudprint_package:
  pip.installed:
    - name: git+https://github.com/forked/cloudprint.git
```

The *cloudprint* package is installed, but Salt is re-installing it on each successive state run:

```
----------
          ID: cloudprint_package
    Function: pip.installed
        Name: git+https://github.com/forked/cloudprint.git
      Result: True
     Comment: There was no error installing package 
              'git+https://github.com/forked/cloudprint.git' 
              although it does not show when calling 'pip.freeze'.
     Started: 21:37:18.772181
    Duration: 38152.208 ms
     Changes:   
              ----------
              git+https://github.com/forked/cloudprint.git==???:
                  Installed
```

**Question:** How do I prevent it from reinstalling the package?

Answer (score 0):

Output of `pip freeze | grep -i cloudprint`

```
cloudprint==0.11
```

**Solution:** Specify an *egg* identifier to the pip command:

```
cloudprint_package:
  pip.installed:
    - name: git+https://github.com/forked/cloudprint.git#egg=cloudprint==0.11
```